# State not Updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Please I am new to React, I have this code, I jsust can not understand why ClickCard is not getting change after this line  **setClickCard([...ClickCard, index]);** the state is changed when I click on two different cards(when the function click is called again) , the state then will have the first index.

```
 const click = index => {
    if (ClickCard.length < 2 && !Card[index].isFlipped) {
      const newCard = Card.map((tile, i) =>
        i === index ? { ...tile, isFlipped: true } : tile
      );
      setCard(newCard);
      setClickCard([...ClickCard, index]);
      console.log(ClickCard);
     
      console.log(ClickCard.length);
      if (ClickCard.length === 1) {
        console.log("  =====1");
        const firstIndex = ClickCard;
        if (Card[firstIndex].value === Card[index].value) {
          setClickCard([]);
          
        } else { console.log("not the same");
        
        }
      }

   
    }
   
  };
```

Comment: if you can try and explain a bit better what you're trying to do can help. Also show the rest of component with state hook etc..

Comment: if index is a card property maybe you want `setClickCard({...ClickCard, index});`  instead of spreading array but almost a guess at this point.

Comment: I just can not understand why inside the function the setClickCard is not changing but if I display the ClikCard outside the function it is getting changed on each click

Comment: did you sort it out?

Comment: In fact, what I understand is that's not a problem the usestate is asyn that's why it's not modified within the UseEffect.